# Is "would" accompanied with present perfect?

Tags: conditional-constructions, verb-forms

> "Ah, poor James!" she said. "God knows we done all we
>   could, as poor as we are—we wouldn't see him want anything while he
>   was in it."
>    Nannie had leaned her head against the
>   sofa-pillow and seemed about to fall asleep.
>    
>   "There's poor Nannie," said Eliza, looking at her, "she's wore out.
>   All the work we had, she and me, getting in the woman to wash him and
>   then laying him out and then the coffin and then arranging about the
>   Mass in the chapel. Only for Father O'Rourke **I don't know what we'd
>   have done at all**. It was him brought us all them flowers and them
>   two candlesticks out of the chapel and wrote out the notice for the
>   Freeman's General and took charge of all the papers for the cemetery
>   and poor James's insurance." (James Joyce, Dubliners)

What has ‘would’ been put in the clause for? 
When I back-shift the sentence, “I didn't know what we'd do at all”, it’s not likely what the context says. Is the original a present perfect, and ‘would’ is weakening the meaning of ‘don’t know’? (or does 'only for' mean 'without'?)

Comment: If you said "I didn't know what we'd do at all", then you'd probably want to follow it with "It **is** him **that is bringing** us all them flowers...".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the consequence clause of a conditional construction in which the condition clause is headed by *only for*.

*Only for* means “but for, if it were not for”; your *without* is a pretty good guess. It was at one time generally current in informal use, but [*OED 1*](http://archive.org/stream/oed07arch#page/128/mode/2up), s.v. **Only, B.** *Conjunctive adv.,conj. (prep.)* **2.** says (in 1902) that is ‘Now only *dial.*’, and it does not appear in either the Oxford Dictionaries or in Merriam-Webster. The dialectal use is however fairly widespread: I heard it occasionally in Alabama in the 1950s and 1960s, and in the Ozarks in the 1980s. It is hardly surprising that it should have been current in Joyce's Dublin; Bernard Shaw, a generation older than Joyce, observes somewhere that the Dublin of his youth was an 18th-century town.

*At all* at the end of a sentence is an Irishism; *entirely* may also occur in this position, with the same sense.

So the sentence may be paraphrased:

> If it were not for Father O'Rourke I have absolutely no idea what we would have done.

Comment: The dictionary you linked is very helpful to get lots of information. But that’s not the whole. May I ask you how to access to all? I don’t find the course yet.

Comment: @Listenever I've posted links at the bottom of [this Meta answer](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/a/739/32).

Answer (score 0):

I would go there---Conditional tense.

I would have gone there---Conditional Perfect tense.

I would be going there---Conditional Progressive tense.

I would have been going there---Conditional Perfect Progressive tense.